# serving static files in heroku with django

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, static

I'm deploying a Django app in heroku, but the static files doesnt work. I was looking I i suppose that I have the right configuration.

settings.py

```
import os
RUTA_PROYECTO = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(RUTA_PROYECTO,'static'),
)
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Portafolio6.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But this still not working. 
Please help.

Comment: Did you run "python manage.py collectstatic" ?

Comment: No, what is that? I'll check it, is because Im new in heroku

Answer (score 2):

I've also been running into issues with [collectstatic not running automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413149/why-isnt-collectstatic-being-run-automatically-when-i-deploy-my-django-app-to-h) when I deploy my Django app to Heroku, but a temporary fix at least would be to add `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` to your `Procfile`, e.g.

```
web: python my_django_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput ; gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_app.wsgi:application
```