# Why isn't collectstatic being run automatically when I deploy my Django app to Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, static-files, procfile

I've followed the official [Heroku docs on Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets); I've installed `dj-static` and added it to my `requirements.txt` file, properly configured all the variables in my `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CONFIG_ROOT, 'served/static/')                       
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                         

STATICFILES_DIRS = (                                                            
    os.path.join(CONFIG_ROOT, 'static'),                                        
)
```

And this is what my `wsgi.py` looks like:

```
import os                                                                       
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_django_project.settings")                                                                 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

The contents of `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_project.wsgi:application
```

In the docs, it says that "collectstatic is run automatically when it is configured properly." But when I navigate to my site there's clearly no css.

I've tried [debugging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#debugging) using `heroku run`, but that just copies the static files as expected.

I've noticed that when I include the `collectstatic` command in my `Procfile`, i.e.

```
web: python my_django_project/manage.py collectstatic --noinput ; gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_project.wsgi:application
```

...that works as expected, and the static files are served.

However what's strange about that is when I run `heroku run bash` and look inside the directory that `STATIC_ROOT` is pointing to, there's nothing there! In fact, the entire `served/` directory is missing, and yet, the static files are still being served!

I'd still like to know why isn't `collectstatic` being run automatically though -- like mentioned in the docs -- when I deploy my Django app to Heroku.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15858757/263989

Comment: @fasouto Tried it; didn't get any errors. I got a bunch of `Pretend to copy '...'` and a `284 static files copied.` message at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might be using a specific settings module for Heroku/production. Further, you've set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to this settings module (and that way, when the app runs, Django knows to use that one and not, say, your default/development one). Finally, you've probably configured static asset settings in Heroku/production settings module (perhaps, `STATIC_ROOT`).

Okay, so if this is all correct, then here is the issue:  **heroku environment variables are only set at serve-time, not at compile-time**. This is important because **`collectstatic` is a compile-time operation** for Heroku. (Heroku goes through 2 stages when you push: 1) compiling, which involves setting the application up (`collectstatic`, `syncdb`, etc) 2) serving, the normal operation of your application).

So, essentially, you've done everything correctly, but Heroku hasn't exposed your environment variables, including your specification of a different settings module, to `collectstatic`.

To have your environment variables set to compile-time, enable Heroku's `user-env-compile` lab feature like this:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

I think this is a silly thing to do by default, and would be interested in hearing why Heroku thought it was a good idea.

Comment: FYI this is no longer a valid solution :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904959/failing-to-enable-user-env-compile-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `user_env_compile` setting to your heroku config?

`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile`

With that enabled collectstatic should be run whenever you deploy to heroku automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [heroku python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) with dokku, and collectstatic was not being run because it had no *execute* permission. They fixed that in a [recent commit](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/5ecd27e3b8053ad72b4c78dac6e556c479c0dfe2) (Dec 13, 2013), so it should work now.