# failing to enable user-env-compile on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, secret-key

it is the first time I ask for something so sorry if I'm not enough precise!

I tried to upload my rails app on heroku using enabling the user-env-compile to manage my secret keys but I have an error "No such feature: user-env-compile".

I checked on Heroku devcenter and seems that user-env-compile has been deprecated and replaced by the ENV_DIR argument.

Here the link: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

I cant really get what to do! can someone explain better to me what I'm supposed to do?

thank you,

Federico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything (the labs is deprecated and you should delete it), by default now heroku is exporting your environement variables during slug compilation.

Be careful, it is not recommended to use the environement variable during slug compilation (you can check http://12factor.net/ for more informations)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Luc
thank you but what about the secret keys?
can I use 'heroku config:set' or is unsafe?

I found it here :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: You can and should use heroku config:set to define your secret as environement variables. You should never put any of your credentials in your git repository. heroku config-vars are a safe place to store your credentials.

Comment: I don't think this is the case as of right now. Heroku IS NOT exporting variables during compilation, at least with the default ruby build pack.

Comment: It seem like heroku is exporting something called ENV_DIR that passed as the 3rd argument to the compile method which is loaded into `user_env_hash` for the ruby build pack